# Hibernate: org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException

Tags: hibernate, join, hibernate-mapping

I am using hibernate to handle database transactions.

**I have 2 entities :**

- SegmentFileEntity
- SegmentFileMappingEntity

**SegmentFileEntity can have one or more SegmentFileMappingEntity. Join key is SEGMENT_FILE_ID which is primary key in**

**Associated table structure for SegmentFileEntity :**

```
CREATE TABLE OAP_META_NEW.SEGMENT_FILE
(
  SEGMENT_FILE_ID    NUMBER(10)                 DEFAULT OAP_META_NEW.SEGMENT_FILE_SEQ.NEXTVAL CONSTRAINT SEGMENTFILEID_NOTNULL NOT NULL,
  SEGMENT_FILE_PATH  VARCHAR2(500 BYTE)         CONSTRAINT SEGMENTFILEPATH_NOTNULL NOT NULL,
  CLIENT_ID          NUMBER(10)                 CONSTRAINT SEGMENTFILE_CLIENTID_NOTNULL NOT NULL,
  INSERT_DATE        DATE                       NOT NULL
)
```

**And details of contraints on that table :**

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

**Associated table structure for SegmentFileMappingEntity:**

```
CREATE TABLE OAP_META_NEW.SEGMENT_FILE_MAPPING
(
  SEGMENT_FILE_MAPPING_ID  NUMBER(10)           DEFAULT OAP_META_NEW.SEGMENT_FILE_MAPPING_SEQ.NEXTVAL CONSTRAINT SFM_SFMID_NOTNULL NOT NULL,
  SEGMENT_FILE_ID          NUMBER(10) CONSTRAINT SFM_SEGMENTFILEID_NOTNULL NOT NULL,
  ATTRIBUTE_POSITION       NUMBER(3) CONSTRAINT SFM_ATTRIBUTEPOSITION_NOTNULL NOT NULL,
  ATTRIBUTE_NAME           VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) CONSTRAINT SFM_ATTRIBUTENAME_NOTNULL NOT NULL
)
```

And the details of the constraints on that table:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

**Here is the test that I am running on these entities:**

```
public class SegmentFileTest
    extends AbstractTest
{
    private long attCatId;
    private int attCatTypeId;
    private long attDelimitedSavedId;
    private long attFixedSavedId;
    private long attDerivedSavedId;

    SegmentFileService segmentFileService;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUpAttributeCategoryTypeAttributeCategory()
    {
        segmentFileService = context.getBean( SegmentFileService.class );


    }

    @Test
    public void saveSegmentFile()
    {

        //Create segment-file
        SegmentFileEntity segmentFile = new SegmentFileEntity();
        segmentFile.setClientId( 0 );
        segmentFile.setSegmentFilePath( "/fakepath/" );
        segmentFile.setInsertDate( new Date((new java.util.Date()).getTime()));

        //Create segment-file-mapping
        List<SegmentFileMappingEntity> fileMappings = new ArrayList<SegmentFileMappingEntity>( );

        SegmentFileMappingEntity segmentFileMapping1 = new SegmentFileMappingEntity();
        segmentFileMapping1.setAttributeName( "attr1" );
        segmentFileMapping1.setAttributePosition( 1 );

        SegmentFileMappingEntity segmentFileMapping2 = new SegmentFileMappingEntity();
        segmentFileMapping2.setAttributeName( "attr2" );
        segmentFileMapping2.setAttributePosition( 2 );

        fileMappings.add(segmentFileMapping1);
        fileMappings.add(segmentFileMapping2);

        segmentFile.setSegmentFileAttributeMappings( fileMappings );
        segmentFileService.saveSegmentFileEntity( segmentFile );


    }
}
```

**Problem :**

If I use only 1 SegmentFileMappingEntity while saving SegmentFileEntity, it is fine. But if I use more than 1 SegmentFileMappingEntity , while saving SegmentFileEntity, I am seeing the error:

```
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session. Any insight?
```

**Here are my java-hibernate entities:**

**SegmentFileEntity: **

```
package com.company.online.segment.api.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;




@Entity
@Table( name = "SEGMENT_FILE", schema = "OAP_META_NEW" )
@SequenceGenerator( name = "segment_file_seq", sequenceName = "OAP_META_NEW.SEGMENT_FILE_SEQ" )
public class SegmentFileEntity implements Serializable
{

    private int segmentFileId;
    private String segmentFilePath;
    private int clientId;
    private Date insertDate;

    @Id
    @Column( name = "SEGMENT_FILE_ID" , nullable = false, unique = true, precision = 0 )
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "segment_file_seq" )
    @JoinColumn(name = "SEGMENT_FILE_ID", referencedColumnName = "SEGMENT_FILE_ID")
    public int getSegmentFileId()
    {
        return segmentFileId;
    }

    public void setSegmentFileId( int segmentFileId )
    {
        this.segmentFileId = segmentFileId;
    }

    @Basic @Column( name = "SEGMENT_FILE_PATH" ) public String getSegmentFilePath()
    {
        return segmentFilePath;
    }

    public void setSegmentFilePath( String segmentFilePath )
    {
        this.segmentFilePath = segmentFilePath;
    }

    @Basic @Column( name = "CLIENT_ID" ) public int getClientId()
    {
        return clientId;
    }

    public void setClientId( int clientId )
    {
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }

    @Basic @Column( name = "INSERT_DATE" )
    public Date getInsertDate()
    {
        return insertDate;
    }

    public void setInsertDate( Date insertDate )
    {
        this.insertDate = insertDate;
    }

    @Override public boolean equals( Object o )
    {
        if ( this == o )
            return true;
        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() )
            return false;

        SegmentFileEntity that = (SegmentFileEntity) o;

        if ( segmentFileId != that.segmentFileId )
            return false;
        if ( clientId != that.clientId )
            return false;
        if ( segmentFilePath != null ? !segmentFilePath.equals( that.segmentFilePath ) : that.segmentFilePath != null )
            return false;
        if ( insertDate != null ? !insertDate.equals( that.insertDate ) : that.insertDate != null )
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override public int hashCode()
    {
        int result = segmentFileId;
        result = 31 * result + ( segmentFilePath != null ? segmentFilePath.hashCode() : 0 );
        result = 31 * result + clientId;
        result = 31 * result + ( insertDate != null ? insertDate.hashCode() : 0 );
        return result;
    }


    private List<SegmentFileMappingEntity> segmentFileAttributeMappings;

    @OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER , orphanRemoval = true )
    @JoinColumn( name = "SEGMENT_FILE_ID", referencedColumnName = "SEGMENT_FILE_ID", nullable = false)
    public List<SegmentFileMappingEntity> getSegmentFileAttributeMappings()
    {
        return segmentFileAttributeMappings;
    }

    public void setSegmentFileAttributeMappings( List<SegmentFileMappingEntity> segmentFileAttributeMappings )
    {
        this.segmentFileAttributeMappings = segmentFileAttributeMappings;
    }
}
```

**SegmentFileMappingEntity :**

```
package com.company.online.segment.api.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;


@Entity @Table( name = "SEGMENT_FILE_MAPPING", schema = "OAP_META_NEW" )
public class SegmentFileMappingEntity implements Serializable
{

    private int segmentFileMappingId;
    private int segmentFileId;
    private int attributePosition;
    private String attributeName;

    @Id @Column( name = "SEGMENT_FILE_MAPPING_ID" ) public int getSegmentFileMappingId()
    {
        return segmentFileMappingId;
    }

    public void setSegmentFileMappingId( int segmentFileMappingId )
    {
        this.segmentFileMappingId = segmentFileMappingId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column( name = "SEGMENT_FILE_ID", nullable = false, precision = 0, updatable = false, insertable = false )
    public int getSegmentFileId()
    {
        return segmentFileId;
    }

    public void setSegmentFileId( int segmentFileId )
    {
        this.segmentFileId = segmentFileId;
    }

    @Basic @Column( name = "ATTRIBUTE_POSITION" ) public int getAttributePosition()
    {
        return attributePosition;
    }

    public void setAttributePosition( int attributePosition )
    {
        this.attributePosition = attributePosition;
    }

    @Basic @Column( name = "ATTRIBUTE_NAME" ) public String getAttributeName()
    {
        return attributeName;
    }

    public void setAttributeName( String attributeName )
    {
        this.attributeName = attributeName;
    }

    @Override public boolean equals( Object o )
    {
        if ( this == o )
            return true;
        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() )
            return false;

        SegmentFileMappingEntity that = (SegmentFileMappingEntity) o;

        if ( segmentFileMappingId != that.segmentFileMappingId )
            return false;
        if ( segmentFileId != that.segmentFileId )
            return false;
        if ( attributePosition != that.attributePosition )
            return false;
        if ( attributeName != null ? !attributeName.equals( that.attributeName ) : that.attributeName != null )
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override public int hashCode()
    {
        int result = segmentFileMappingId;
        result = 31 * result + segmentFileId;
        result = 31 * result + attributePosition;
        result = 31 * result + ( attributeName != null ? attributeName.hashCode() : 0 );
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `SegmentFileMappingEntity` you annotated your accessor for the field `segmentFileMappingId` with `@Id` so hibernate will use it as database identifier. This means it has to be unique for every object row.

But you did not provide a value for it.

Hence it is an integer it's default value is 0, so every of your created `SegmentFileMappingEntity` instances gets 0 as identifier during object creation. Within your current session / persistence context this is "accidentally ok" for one entry, saving a second one is not possible.

The solution would be to either generate an unique value for every instance on application level or let hibernate generate one for you (like you already did with the database sequence for your `SegmentFileEntity` accessor `getSegmentFileId()`).

See [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-identifier) for more information.